# Can we use excel4node for commercial

Tags: license, npm

Now I am using `excel4node` in my product. `excel4node` is using `jszip` which using `openent`. `excel4node` is under MIT license, `jszip` under both MIT and GPl license, but `openent` is GPL licence. So can I use `excel4node` for my product ?

A ticket relate to openent and jszip license: https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/650

[image]

Comment: Some possibilities that might cause a false-positive result in BlackDuck are that openent is used for building or testing jszip but is not needed when using it. Another possibility might be that one of the zip files used for testing is actually a zip of openent.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, both the MIT and GPL licenses are open source licenses (as defined by the [Open Source Definition](https://opensource.org/osd)), so you can use them for any purpose, including commercially. If jszip and thus excel4node are using a GPL component, then you would have to comply with the terms of the GPL which basically means making your source code available if you are distributing your program to anyone outside your organisation.

However... this whole thing looks like a Black Duck false positive to me. It really doesn't look like jszip includes [openent](https://openent.adullact.net/) in any way at all. It would be somewhat surprising if it did, as jszip is JavaScript and openent seems to be pretty much pure Java; I'm guessing that there's some remarkably generic file in openent which is being flagged by Black Duck. Another important note here is that Black Duck seems to think openent is GNU AGPL licensed, which is a different license from the GNU GPL and requires you to distribute the code even if people only interact with your program via a computer network.

That all said, you shouldn't trust the word of a random poster on the Internet. If you have concerns, you need to talk to your lawyers.